# The Minimalist Program and Features

Tags: minimalism, movement

In MP, constituents move as a last resort in order to get certain features checked. For example, subjects in English move from within the predicate of a sentence to SpecIP in order to get its strong EPP feature checked (Adger). What about focus-moved constituents? What feature causes them to move? A strong contrastive focus feature?

It seems to me that features are created on an ad hoc basis to account for movement as a last resort such that someone could easily whip up some feature nobody has ever heard of to explain an instance of movement. Is there any restriction on the type and number of features there can be?